# Add html to li for active-trail menu links

Tags: theming

Ive used the theme override below to add a span to the end of the li of my menu links. This is working but I need it so the span is only added to the active-train li.

```
function MYTHEMENAME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . ' <span>Something</span> ' . "</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class']` contain `active-trail` class and create your custom span based on this information.

```
function MYTHEMENAME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  $span = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  if (isset($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'])) {
    if (in_array('active-trail', $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'])) {
      $span = '<span>Something</span>';
    }
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . $span . "</li>\n";
}
```